# How to add regex to attribute name in custom validations in Laravel?

Tags: regex, laravel, laravel-validation

In custom validation as shown below:

```
'custom' => array(
    'attribute-name' => array(
        'rule-name' => 'custom-message',
    ),
),
```

How is it possible to define regex along with the attribute-name-{regex} as well?!

Example:

```
 'custom' => array(
    'institute_regex:{/d{1}}' => array(
            'required' => 'the field is required',
        ),
),
```

Comment: what are you asking???

Comment: @AmitJoki rule-name can be defined as required where the attribute should be entered. I need to make sure also that the attribute is a regex as well.

Comment: Sth like [this](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation#rule-regex)?

Comment: I've read at a couple of times and I don't know what exactly you want to achieve. What is `custom` here? Is it validator or what? Please explain in details what you want to achieve. Do you want to display custom messages for each regex you define or maybe you want to make validation for institute_field only if it matches regex?

Comment: custom here is the custom array in validation.php where i can define a custom error message rather than default one.The issue now is that the error is displayed english and whenever the user changes the language, that should also reflect on the error message as well. Regex would have helped by changing the attribute name not value where i would seearch for certain paattern and decide wether to display error or not.

Comment: found any solution for this? Just facing the same issue ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think that might be what you were looking for ages ago, but anyway, here is what I did.

Had to find a way to define custom validation messages (in another language) for inputs dynamically generated in the frontend. The result is that I would get the following type of classes:

`project_name-1, -2, -3 etc to keep it simple.`

So what I did, and it worked just fine for me was adding the following lines to my `validation.php` file (whatever the language is):

```
'project_name-*' => [
    'required' => 'Please name your project.',
],
```

And voilà, I hope it will help someone!